# Request a post to be unprotected

Tags: feature-request, support, protected-questions

Since questions can be protected, there should be a way to unprotect them. There is currently a question with an answer that the poster indicates is less than desirable. I have a better solution after encountering the same issue but the question can't be answered by people with a reputation under 10 and I only signed-up so I could share the better answer.

The "Protected" rule is current preventing a better answer from being given to a question. Some people would call that restriction of output and some companies would fire you for it... I've seen it happen.

A "Request exception" or "Request unprotect" feature should be implemented, wherein the requestor would provide the answer they intend to post with their request and a moderator could approve it at which point the post would become visible. (Note that it takes 15 reputation to be able to flag a post for moderator attention, so flags cannot be used for this.)

In the mean time, how do I increase my reputation so I can contribute a better answer? Don't believe it's a better answer? Contact me and I'll prove it. It completely solves the OPs issue using the exact parameters the OP wanted to use. Check it out @ [HTTP 500 error when user not logged into Facebook on a Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378801/http-500-error-when-user-not-logged-into-facebook-on-a-windows-phone-7).

Comment: Also, when I posted a new question linking to the one that was locked and started waiting the 8 hours to post the answer, I woke up this morning to find out that my question had been completely deleted from the site. It's a valid question and I have the answer, why can't I just share it with the community?

Comment: The locked under 10 rule *is* useful on high-traffic posts which tend to attract an awful lot of answers for years that don't say anything much over what's already there and don't say it particularly well either. It also prevents a certain class of spamming too.

Comment: I answered a question and got the reputation I Need and was finally ableto submit my edit and my answer to that post. You can use display=wap|touch and get the desired effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions are protected to reduce the number of not-an-answer posts like "Thank you" for questions with a high number of views. The usual way to get a question unprotected would be to flag for a moderator, which you can't with 1 reputation (15 rep are needed).

I can understand that it is frustrating when you encounter a question you're not allowed to answer, and sometimes protecting a question might prevent better answers from being posted. That is why it should only be used sparingly, and questions are often unprotected when the traffic decreases a bit again.

Your proposed mechanism sounds very similar to the ability to suggest edits. A problem I see is that it creates additional work for those that review the answers. I think it could work, but I'm not sure if it is worth the effort in development. But that is really something for the SE team to decide.

You only need 10 reputation to be able to post to protected questions, and 10 reputation is really easy to get. That is one upvote for an answer, 2 upvotes to a question or 5 suggested edits. If you provide one reasonable answer, that is often enough to get the 10 reputation you need.

Comment: Now that any 15k user can unprotect any question, it might be better to ask this in chat or even comments (instead of involving a moderator)